# List files with pyftp - proftpd vs. pyftpdlib behavior

Tags: python, ftp, proftpd, pyftpdlib

I have a test code which uses an FTP stub with pyftpdlib, which to my surprise failed in production. The reason for this is that proftpd returns the directory name in response to `NLST`. Here is the response from `pyftpdlib` FTP stub:

```
In [10]: local_conn.login('user', '12345')
Out[10]: '230 Login successful.'

In [11]: import ftplib

In [12]: local_conn = ftplib.FTP()

In [13]: local_conn.connect('localhost', 2121)
Out[13]: '220 pyftpdlib 1.4.0 ready.'

In [14]: local_conn.login('user', '12345')
Out[14]: '230 Login successful.'

In [15]: local_conn.nlst('structuredata_advanced')
Out[15]: 
['Report_20150618.csv',
 'Report_20150618.fin',
 'Report_20150619.csv',
 'Report_20150619.fin',
 'Report_20150620.csv',
 'Report_20150620.fin']
```

Here is the response from `proftpd`:

```
In [16]: remote_conn = ftplib.FTP()

In [17]: remote_conn.connect('A1B.7Y.XX.XX', 21)
Out[17]: '220 ProFTPD 1.3.4a Server (vztd3.company.com) [A1B.7Y.XX.XX]'

In [18]: remote_conn.login('remoteuser', 'verysecret')
Out[18]: '230 User yougov logged in'

In [19]: remote_conn.nlst('structuredata_advanced')
Out[19]: 
['structuredata_advanced/Report_20150624.csv',
 'structuredata_advanced/Report_20150629.csv',
 'structuredata_advanced/Report_20150625.fin',
 'structuredata_advanced/Report_20150628.fin',
 'structuredata_advanced/Report_20150627.fin',
 'structuredata_advanced/Report_20150620.fin',
 'structuredata_advanced/Report_20150619.csv', 
  ...]
```

It's easy enough to remove those directory names:

```
    # this code works both in production and testing 
    files = conn.nlst(basedir)
    # proftd is weired it returns the basedir name too
    files = [f.split('/')[-1] for f in files]
```

but I would like to understand if this is something that pyftpdlib does wrong?
Is this something that can be configured in `ProFTPD`?
Is there something I need to know about the FTP protocol and NLST command?

### update

I just tested another ftp server called [`uftpd`](https://github.com/troglobit/uftpd/) it behaves like `pyftpdlib` when issuing `NLST`.

Comment: if 'structuredata_advanced' is not the current directory, the server should return the path name 'structuredata_advanced' prepended. check the current dir with `con.pwd()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the author of [uftpd](https://github.com/troglobit/uftpd/).

I just googled a bit, turns out [DJB wrote aboute this](http://cr.yp.to/ftp/list.html) a while back, and unfortunately it seems output differs between servers.

My interpretation though is; that it is recommended to *not* prefix each output file in a given directory with the directory name.  I.e., if the client sends 'NLST dir' the server should *not* reply:

```
dir/a
dir/b
```

but instead simply output the files in directory `dir/` like this:

```
a
b
```